# Scala - template method pattern in a trait

Tags: scala, apache-spark, design-patterns, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm implementing a template method pattern in Scala. The idea is that the method returns a `Dataset[Metric]`.

But when I'm converting enrichedMetrics to a DataSet `enrichedMetrics.as[Metric]` I have to use implicits in order to map the records to the specified type. This means passing a SparkSession to the `MetricsProcessor` which seems not the best  solution to me.

The solution I see now is to pass `spark: SparkSession` as a parameter to the template method. And then import spark.implicits._ within the template method.

Is there a more proper way to implement the template method pattern in this case?

```
  trait MetricsProcessor  {

  // Template method
  def parseMetrics(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, metricId: Long): Dataset[Metric] = {
    val metricsFromSource: DataFrame = queryMetrics(startDate, endDate)
    val enrichedMetrics = enrichMetrics(metricsFromSource, metricId)
    enrichedMetrics.as[Metric] <--- //requires spark.implicits
  }

  // abstract method
  def queryMetrics(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): DataFrame

  def enrichMetrics(metricsDf: DataFrame, metricId: Long): DataFrame = {
  /*Default implementation*/
  }
 }
```

Comment: Actually you do not require `spark.implicits._` but just one of the implicits it brings, an **Encoder[Metrics]**. You may ask only for that as an implicit parameter of the method. Also, if `Metrics` is a concrete case class, you can create the **Encoder** by yourself, using the `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product` helper method. _(I may have typos, but I hope this can help you)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez could you please provide an example?

Comment: If **Metric** is a type parameter than an user can specify, then `def parseMetrics(...)(implicit encoder: Encoder[Metric]): Dataset[Metric]` _(where the dots are your normal parameters)_. - If **Metric** is a concrete case class, then create a companion object for **MetricProcessor** an put this there `implicit val metricEncoder: Encoder[Metric] = Encoders.product` & either on the body of the trait or on the body of the method add `import MetricProcessor._` - BTW, I would make that method final.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `Encoder` for your type `Metric` here which spark cannot find implicitly, for common types like `String`, `Int` etc, spark has implicit encoders.

Also, you cannot do a simple `.as` on a data frame if the columns in the source type and destination type aren't the same. I'll make some assumptions here.

For a `case class` Metric

```
case class Metric( ??? )
```

the line in `parseMetrics` will change to,

**Option 1 - Explicitly passing the Encoder**

```
enrichedMetrics.map(row => Metric( ??? ))(Encoders.product[Metric])
```

**Option 2 - Implicitly passing the Encoder**

```
implicit val enc : Encoder[Metric] = Encoders.product[Metric]
enrichedMetrics.map(row => Metric( ??? ))
```

Note, as pointed in one of the comments, if your `parseMetric` method is always returning the `Dataset[Metric]`, you can add the implicit encoder to the body of the trait.

Hope this helped.